Navigating in test: `Warning: An update to Animated(View) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`
Background
With the following tests (which navigate from Source to Target):
import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';

import React, {Component, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';

const SourceFunc = ({navigation}) => {
  useEffect(() => navigation.navigate('Target'), [navigation]);
};

class SourceClass extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Target');
  }

  render() {}
}

const Target = () => {}; 

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  it('', async () => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    await render(
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Source" component={SourceFunc} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Target" component={Target} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>,
    );  
  }); 
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  it('', async () => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    await render(
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Source" component={SourceClass} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Target" component={Target} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>,
    );  
  }); 
}

I get a summary like the following:
 PASS  ./test.js
  ✓  (135 ms)
  ✓  (134 ms)
  ✓  (27 ms)
  ✓  (9 ms)
  ✓  (8 ms)
  ✓  (25 ms)
  ✓  (25 ms)
  ✓  (9 ms)
  ✓  (9 ms)
  ✓  (21 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       10 passed, 10 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites matching /test.js/i

and many instances of the much loved warning:
    Warning: An update to Animated(View) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act

As you can see, I am awaiting the render, and doing almost nothing else, so it's very much not clear to me where the "update to Animated(View)" is occurring.
Question
How can we perform navigation in tests without incurring this warning?
Notes

This doesn't occur for a single test run (hence the multiple iterations)
This doesn't occur if each test run finishes (as presented by the summary) in less than ~130ms

Full reproduction
pushd $(mktemp -d)
npx react-native init test
pushd test
yarn add @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/stack react-native-gesture-handler react-native-safe-area-context
yarn add --dev @testing-library/react-native
patch -p1 <<EOF
--- a/jest.config.js
+++ b/jest.config.js
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 module.exports = {
   preset: 'react-native',
+  transformIgnorePatterns: [],
 };
EOF
# add test.js
npx jest test.js


Wrap the Navigation in act(...): This can be done by using the act method from @testing-library/react-native.
Ensure All Updates are Captured: Use waitFor from @testing-library/react-native to ensure all asynchronous updates are awaited properly.
const SourceFunc = ({navigation}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.navigate('Target');
  }, [navigation]);
  return null;
};

class SourceClass extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Target');
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

const Target = () => null;

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  it('navigates from SourceFunc to Target without warnings', async () => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
    await act(async () => {
      const { getByText } = render(
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Source" component={SourceFunc} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Target" component={Target} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>,
      );
    });

    // Ensure navigation is complete by checking for an element in the Target component
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(() => getByText('Target')).not.toThrow();
    });
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  it('navigates from SourceClass to Target without warnings', async () => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
    await act(async () => {
      const { getByText } = render(
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Source" component={SourceClass} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Target" component={Target} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>,
      );
    });

    // Ensure navigation is complete by checking for an element in the Target component
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(() => getByText('Target')).not.toThrow();
    });
  });
}


This fails with Can't access .root on unmounted test renderer (pointing just after render), by eye getByText won't be defined when it's used, and the screen always has the text "Target" as the navigator adds that to the header by default.
